# How come my host file doesn't contain IP address of my frequently visited websites?

Tags: macos, web, ip

I did `vim /etc/hosts` and my hosts file looks like:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

How come it doesn't contain the ip addresses of my frequently visited websites like stackoverflow.com, youtube.com, google.com, twitter.com, etc.. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/etc/hosts file is not for recently visited websites. 
If you don't have a DNS service configured or if you want to add your own server, you can add IP and websites to your hosts file manually.

Comment: Most systems will cache recently looked-up DNS entries, but it's generally stored in memory not in a disk file. In macOS, this is handled by the mDNSResponder process.